# Jquery slideDown not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I cannot figure out why the following will not slideDown slow. Notice that the div is inline.

```
<span id="readMoreLink" style="display: inline"><a style="color: #213d92" class="textlink" id="readMore "href="#"> ...Read More</a></span>
<div id="bioText" style="display: inline">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </div>
```

```js
$('#readMore').click(function (e) {             
    $('#bioText').slideDown(1000);
    $('#readMoreLink').hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

NOTE: If it remove display:inline it works fine. It is the display: inline that is causing the problem. I need the display inline though. Not sure how to get around this.

Comment: Have you tried `e.preventDefault()` before the other code? IIRC it should be the first action.

Comment: How's this different from your last question? BTW, the ID of your element is `readMoreLink` but you're binding with `$('#readMore')`. And why are you sliding down something that's already visible?

Comment: Should we assume you also have an opening/closing <script> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
$('#readMore').click(function (e) {
    $('#bioText').slideToggle(1000);
    $('#readMoreLink').hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHXp9/2/)

Comment: @procrastinator so am I lazy? :P

Comment: Don't worry, I'm one of them too ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the solution to your problem, but note that in your question's sample code you have an extra space on the ID attribute for your  tag:

```
id="readMore " 

<a style="color: #213d92" class="textlink" id="readMore "href="#">
```

There is an extra space before the closing quote.

Your jQuery code does not reproduce that space, so the name of the ID is different.

```
$('#readMore').click(function (e) {
```

---

Your code does work with that fixed: [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v9TyJ/)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. When I remove display:none; it does the effect I am talking about. I need to remove the display:none as I like the text to keep on flowing. Hope this makes sense. Any solution to this?

Comment: I'm sorry Nate, I don't understand what you are requesting. Do you mean, "When you remove the `display:none` from the `div#bioText` in the jsFiddle"? If you need to remove that programmatically, you can use either `$('#elementID').removeAttr('display');` or `$('#elementID').css('display','inline');` or just `$('#elementID').show();`  Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks gibberish. I have a meeting to go to but let me add a note a bit later on what I am talking about.. Thanks